# ping: example.org: No address associated with hostname

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, ubuntu-20.04, resolv.conf, resolve

I am facing a problem I cannot explain:

If I do

```
ping example.org
```

I am getting the result

```
ping: example.org: No address associated with hostname
```

`dig` returns an empty result:

```
dig example.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 11024
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
; example.org.  IN  A

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Feb 28 18:27:28 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

If I ping google, the ping get's a pong. Well - as I am using the built-in resolver:

```
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I thought about checking it's stats

```
systemd-resolve --statistics
```

and flush the cache:

```
systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

But still the domain can not be resolved.

If I add google's `8.8.4.4` to `resolv.conf`, the domain can be resolved. But I don't want to use an external resolver. What did I miss in this case?

Comment: You missed the "NXDOMAIN" in the dig output.  If you are hosting or managing this domain you should be looking at your DNS *SERVER* configuration for example.org. Caches and/or resolver configuration is not causing the server to return the NXDOMAIN.